# Backing up a folder to iCloud which is not in the iCloud Drive

Tags: icloud, backup

I'd like to make sure that everything in my /work directory (under my user directory) is continually backed up in the event of the loss or destruction of my machine without indexing everything into git projects.  iCloud looks like a good way to do it, **but** I cannot move the /work folder into the iCloud directory, since this will break absolute pathing in several projects.  Can I have copies of /work backed up to iCloud without moving the entire directory to the iCloud Drive?

Comment: Are you asking how to copy the files programmatically to a new location that is cloud synced?

Comment: iCloud is not a backup solution. Invest in an external SSD and use Time Machine.

Comment: The reason that iCloud is not a backup solution is that if you delete a file locally it will be deleted from iCloud - for a backup the file would still be on the backup

Comment: @mmmmmm You can recover deleted files from iCloud for 30 days; though I'd still agree with maintaining a local TM backup as the best solution.

Comment: Or better both.

Answer (score 0):

[Chronosync](https://www.econtechnologies.com/product/chronosync/) can do a one-way synchronise from your /Work folder to a folder inside iCloud Drive. Tasks can be configured to run automatically.

It is primarily a synchronising tool, but it can be configured to preserve deleted files which makes it partially a backup tool.

Download a trial and see if it meets your needs.

Comment: There are free alternatives like rsync + other tools like Carbon Copy Cloner that can do this, Plus CCC can do other backups.

Comment: @mmmmmm I wasn't attempting to cover all the possible ways of doing what the OP wants. I chose the one which seems, to me, to be easy to use and reliable.

Comment: CCC isn't a "free alternative".